# How can I link 2 processes so when one crashes make the other one crash too?

Tags: ipc, named-pipes, blocking, nonblocking

I am writing a bash program that has IPC between two proccesses (A and B) via named pipes. I am worried because if A crashes, B may be blocked indefinitely (and vice versa), because named pipes are blocking. Can I link A and B so, if A crashes, force B to crash too? Any other alternatives to solve this blocking problem would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not run communication in the separate thread and kill it if it's blocked for a long time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need an additional process "C" that monitors the activity of process "A" and process "B"

Comment: You mean a process that has the pid of A and B and check regularly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a bash script? If so you could trap the signal sent to *A* to kill it and then send a signal to *B* so it exits.

The relevant bash features are: `trap` and `kill`. And the relevant signals would be SIGKILL, SIGINT, SIGHUP, etc. Invoking: `trap -l` will list all the possible signals.